# How to keep seeing the updated value during a While loop?

Tags: dynamic

```
z = 0;
While[
    z < 10^240,
    Dynamic[Refresh[z++]]
]
```

I don't want to use `Print[z]` in this case, as it will generate too much outputs.

For example, how do I get an upated value, while the loop is processing? I just need to `see` for value getting bigger and bigger in this dummy case.

Thanks.

Comment: See [`Monitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a ProgressIndicator:

```
z = 0;
ProgressIndicator[Dynamic[z/(10^7)]]
While[z < 10^7, z++]
```

Now you see a progress indicator moving across from start to completion. If you want to see the actual values of z, this is easy too...

```
Dynamic[z]
z = 0;
While[z < 10^7, z++]
```

Now you can see z incrementing numerically instead of graphically.